# Javascript: Convert array of objects with opening times to single string

Tags: javascript

As an input I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "weekday": "Monday",
    "openFrom": "09:00",
    "openUntil": "19:00",
  },
  {
    "weekday": "Tuesday",
    "openFrom": "09:00",
    "openUntil": "19:00",
  },
  {
    "weekday": "Wednesday",
    "openFrom": "09:00",
    "openUntil": "19:00",
  },
  {
    "weekday": "Thursday",
    "openFrom": "09:00",
    "openUntil": "19:00",
  },
  {
    "weekday": "Friday",
    "openFrom": "09:00",
    "openUntil": "19:00",
  },
  {
    "weekday": "Saturday",
    "openFrom": "08:00",
    "openUntil": "16:00",
  }
]
```

And want to create a function that returns an array of strings like:

```
["Mo–Fr 9:00–19:00", "Sa 08:00–16.00"]
```

I've tried to find a way around it by iterating and checking if the previous index had the same value, but I only get it together as long as the opening times don't change.

So far I have:

```
  const initialOpening = market.openingHoursMarket[0]

  let opening = {
    days: [initialOpening?.weekday],
    hours: [initialOpening?.openFrom, initialOpening?.openUntil],
  }

  market.openingHoursMarket.forEach(({weekday, openFrom, openUntil}, index) => {
    const lastItem = market.openingHoursMarket[index - 1]
    if (index > 0 || (open_from === lastItem?.openFrom && openUntil === lastItem?.openUntil)) {
      opening.days.push(weekday)
    }
  })
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "days": [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ],
  "hours": [
    "09:00",
    "19:00"
  ]
}
```

Here I can then put the string together. I would need a second object though that contains the different hours for Saturday.

Comment: Please share what you have tried in js. so I can go through the code and look where is the issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: @marcoPagni when you said "as long as the opening times don't change" what exactly do you ,mean. Provide the instance. All the object in the array you presented here has the same opening time except for Saturday.

Comment: Thanks, @AbayomiApetu. I've added how far I've come so far. In this example, the opening times on Saturdays are different than on the other days of the week. I have other instances though where you have the same opening hours from Monday to Saturday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have issues with edge cases, but assuming the days are always in order and never contain multiple ranges, and never extend beyond one full week, here's a stab at something that might work for you to build against:

```js
function getGroups(input) {
  // we want to reduce our input array into a (probably smaller) array
  let aggregated = input.reduce((aggr, obj) => {
    // grab the last element in our range -- we'll use this to compare against
    let prev = aggr[aggr.length - 1]

    // if there isn't a previous (this is the first), then we just add it
    if (!prev) {
      aggr.push(obj)
    } else if (obj.openFrom === prev.openFrom && obj.openUntil === prev.openUntil) {
      // update the previous one to include this range (by weekday name), do not modify array
      prev.untilWeekday = obj.weekday
    } else {
      // it's a new range, add it.
      aggr.push(obj)
    }

    return aggr
  }, [])

  // we now have an array that resembles our input, except aggregated days appear as a start (weekday prop) and end (untilWeekday prop). So we need to map these to strings accordingly:
  return aggregated.map((obj) => {
    let abbreviatedWeekday = obj.weekday.substr(0, 2)

    // if this object represents an aggregate of days, we add the untilWeekday prop to the end abbreviated
    if (obj.untilWeekday) {
      abbreviatedWeekday += `-${obj.untilWeekday.substr(0, 2)}`
    }

    return `${abbreviatedWeekday} ${obj.openFrom}-${obj.openUntil}`
  })
}
```

Comment: Ahhh....the magic `reduce` function. I had the feeling the answer lies there, but I'm not familiar enough with it yet. This solution works like a charm for my use case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let the code speak for itself.
Note that this code will work for your specific case. You need to use other approach if want to singularise weekdays in the middle of sequence. For example if all weekdays but Wednesday have the same opening hours and you want array like `['Mo-Tu', 'We', 'Th-Fr']`. With this solution you'll get `['Mo-Fr', 'We']`.

Also note that sorting array by weekdays is up to you.

```
// we'll use it as a key to group weekdays
function parseHours({ openFrom, openUntil }) {
  return `${openFrom}-${openUntil}`;
}

// returns just 2 first letters
function cutWeekday(x) {
  return x.slice(0, 2);
}

// group weekdays with the same opening hours
function groupHours(input) {
  const result = {};
  for (const x of input) {
    const hours = parseHours(x);
    const weekday = cutWeekday(x.weekday);
    if (result[hours]) {
      // if this key already exists in our result map just push another weekday
      result[hours].push(weekday);
    } else {
      // if not create new array containing only this weekday
      result[hours] = [weekday]
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// first element from array
function first(x) {
  return x[0];
}

// last element from array
function last(x) {
  return x[x.length - 1];
}

function pretty(hours, weekdays) {
  // we need to create range for more than 1 weekdays with the same opening hours
  if (weekdays.length > 1) {
    return `${first(weekdays)}-${last(weekdays)} ${hours}`;
  } else {
    return `${first(weekdays)} ${hours}`;
  }
}

function solution(input) {
  const result = []
  const grouped = groupHours(input);
  for (const [hours, weekdays] of Object.entries(grouped)) {{
    result.push(pretty(hours, weekdays));
  }}
  return result
}

solution(input);
```