# Data massaging an array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, arraylist

I have the below array.

```
Const array = [
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Thursday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Friday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  }
]
```

I am writing a function in NodeJs to handle this kind of array where the office hours and days might change based on the office. I am trying to return below value.

```
response = "Mon-Fri 8.30-5pm Closed Sat & Sun"
```

Please advise/suggest. Extremely grateful.

Comment: what have you written so far, would you mind sharing more details?

Comment: so if we change `beginHour` of Wednesday how should output look like ?. Like `"Mon-Fri 8.30-5pm, wed 9-4pm, Closed Sat & Sun` ? that doesn't look good.
I hope you understand complexity here & I don't think its worth it.

Comment: found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645462/javascript-convert-array-of-objects-with-opening-times-to-single-string

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution.... Try it out:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Thursday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Friday",
    "beginHour": "08:30:00",
    "endHour": "17:00:00"
  }
];

//create a function 
const days = arr => {
  //get days and time
  const [mon,fri] = [arr[0],arr[arr.length-1]];
  //destructure
  const [dayM,openM,closeM] = Object.values(mon);
  const [dayF,openF,closeF] = Object.values(fri);
  
  return `${dayM}-${dayF} ${openM}-${closeF} Closed Sat & Sun.`;
};

console.log(days(array));
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, but not reflected well in the example data, any given office has arbitrary hours. Making assumptions about a given day, consecutive days, open v. closed days, etc may not be possible. Consider an office that’s open Mon & Tue from 9-5, closed Wednesdays, open Thu & Fri from 8-4, and open Sat from 9-1.